# SilverStripe change $menu_icon in CMSPageController

Tags: silverstripe

I'm trying to change the `$menu_icon` variable in `CMSPageController` without editing core files (IE: the icon next to menu item "Pages" in the CMS). I went on a limb and tried the following:

1: Define an extension to `CMSPageController` in **_config.yml**

```
CMSPageController:
  extensions:
    - ChangeMenuIcon
```

2: Define class and extend from `CMSPageControllerExtension` in **mysite**

```
class ChangeMenuIcon extends CMSPageControllerExtension {
    private static $menu_icon = 'framework/admin/images/menu-icons/16x16/information.png';
}
```

This results in a 500 error. Is this actually the correct way to overwrite an existing (core) class property?

Comment: Just FYI: you got a 500 error, because there's no `CMSPageControllerExtension` class. Your extension should be a subclass of `LeftAndMainExtension` or just plainly `Extension`. Using the config system as explained in the answer is better anyway, so stick with that.

Comment: Oh I thought by putting that stuff in the .yml file I just created that `CMSPageControllerExtension` class. Wrong assumption I guess!

Comment: No classes are generated based on configuration. In case of extensions, you write the classes and use the config system to apply them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faloude, since it's a private static you could try setting it directly in the `config.yml` rather than applying an extension.

```
CMSPagesController:
  menu_icon: 'framework/admin/images/menu-icons/16x16/information.png';
```

Comment: Cheers that does seem to work. In my code I'm trying to redefine a private static variable. But since `$menu_title` is **private** in the parent class, I can't change the value in a subclass right?

Comment: @Faloude you can just re-define it in your subclass. In a lot of cases private static variables are used for the config system and should not be accessed directly, but rather through `Config`, eg. `Config::inst()->get('MyClass', 'my_static_var')`. Or, in any subclass of `Object`: `$this->config()->my_static_var`

Comment: Interesting, so what's the reason behind this way to access / edit private static variables or more specifically variables in the config system? And what classes fall under the so called *config system*?

Comment: @Faloude: Basically, the config system will allow you to configure whatever you want via YML. Values don't have to exist in code… *if* they exist as static variable in code, the config system will pick that up as the default. Maybe this gives some more information: https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/configuration/configuration/